# Can an instance return values other than a __repr__ string representation?

Tags: python, instance, instance-variables, magic-methods

Here's an example of the phenomenon I'm looking at:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, other):
        self.name = name
        self.other = other

class Name():
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname

class Other():
    def __init__(self, age, stats):
        self.age = age
        self.stats = stats
        self.other = (self.age, self.stats)

    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.age, self.stats)

person_one = Person(Name("John", "Doe"), Other(29, [1, 2, 3]))

print(person_one.name.firstname)
print(person_one.name.lastname)
print(person_one.name.name)
print(person_one.name)

print(person_one.other.age)
print(person_one.other.stats)
print(person_one.other.other)
print(person_one.other)
```

Everything will work fine except from the very last line of code, which will produce a TypeError.  That's because the `__repr__`/`__str__` magic methods will not return anything but a string.

So my question is, is there any way to get a similar functionality that can return non-strings?  I mean, other than using reduplicative instance variables as in the person_one.name.name and person_one.other.other usages?

I saw something that suggested this was possible with the `___new___` magic method, but I'm not sure how that would work.

I know this is not a big deal, and please just tell me if this is not possible at all, but it just seems like a very handy and logical structure to be able to use.

EDIT:

It seems I can get part of the way there by modifying `__call__`.

For example, if I add to `class Other()`:

```
def __call__(self):
        return (self.age, self.stats)
```

Now `person_one.other()` will return the tuple. But it'd still be nice if I could get `person_one.other`itself to return a tuple (without destroying the ability to have `person_one.other.age` etc. return what  want them to).  I'm looking at `__getattribute__`, but so far no luck.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are asking. Why do you want `__repr__` to return something *other than a string*? That's it's entire purpose. Instances *dont' return their `__repr__`*, rather, when a string-form of an instance is required, the `__repr__` is used. I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding something

Comment: So, if you want `print(person_one.other)` to look like `(self.age, self.stats)` why don't you just use `return str((self.age, self.stats))` in your `Other.__repr__`? Generally, and by convention, your `__repr__` should return a string that looks like the source code that would create it, so something to the effect of `return f"Other({self.age}, {self.stats})"`

Comment: repr basically has [two purposes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr): 1. It gives you an understandable idea what a thing is when you see it in interactive mode; 2. It's occasionally a representation of the code used to create an object in the first place. #2 is not always feasible. Either way, these things have to be strings, for #1 because you need to read it in a UI, and #2 because it's code. You sound like you have a #3, which is not going to be what repr is for.

Comment: Thanks!

Yes, I agree that `__repr__` can only return strings.

I just wonder if there is anything I can use to return values other than strings without specifying an instance variable (or method).

So I know i can simply have another instance variable `person_one.other.other` and have it give me a non-string value, just like `person_one.other.age`.

My question is whether I can have `person_one.other` give a non-string value, just like I can have it give a string value using the implicit `__repr__`, as in the `person_one.name` case.

Sorry if this is not clear.

Comment: You have to define your own method, like `def to_tuple(self): return (self.name, self.other)`; there is no standard need to convert an arbitrary object to a tuple representation, so no magic method or hook exists.

Comment: `__str__` and `__repr__` exist because there is typically a reason for `str(x)` and `repr(x)` to work for value of arbitrary types. There's no such need for `tuple(x)` to work for arbitrary values.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks so much!  

As you say: ```__repr__``` is used when a string-form of an instance is required. So that happens when I  use ```person_one.name``` as above.

So then I guess my question is, is there any way to have an arbitrary-form of an instance?  Could I have some usage of ```person_one.name``` get me an int-form or a list-form?

If it's not possible at all, that's fine!  I'm just trying to figure out what is possible.

Comment: @Peter `person_one.name` **has nothing to do with `__repr__`**, that's what I'm trying to tell you. The only reason `__repr__` is involved is because you are `print`ing things

Comment: @Peter *of course* `person.other` can give a non-stirng value, **that's already what it is doing**. Again, you have a fundamental misunderstanding here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for bearing with me!  I definitely understand what you're trying to tell me, and I thank you.

I was just looking for a way for a class instance itself , e.g., ```person_one.name``` or ```person_one.other``` to have arbitrary values, just like instance variables can have, while also preserving the existence of those instance variables.  I just wanted this because it seemed like a logical structure to me. Based on what you and others are saying though, it seems that it is not possible.  That's alright though:  I was just curious.

Comment: @Peter that doesn't make any sense. An instance is *a value*. Python is a strongly-typed langauge, all objects have a well-defined type and know that type. Here's the thing, what you are asking to me *sounds illogical*. What you are showing, e.g. `person.name` and `person.other` **are attribute acceses**, you *could* have them return different values, you can intercept and customize attribute access on Python objects. But you seem to be talking about something else.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you!

You are probably right that I sound illogical.  I am just trying to learn about what is possible, and I am still trying to learn the right terminology.  

So, by intercepting and customizing attribute access on Python objects, could I have `person.other` return a list or any other arbitrary type, while still maintaining the ability for `person.other.age` to return an int and `person.other.stats` to return a list, etc.?  


Thank you so much for bearing with a beginner like me.